# How to include the inputs of the first chain to the second chain in LangChain's SequentialChain?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I receive a list of inputs `['a', 'b']` for the first chain in a `SequentialChain`, and then I have a second chain that receives as input `['a', 'c']`, where `c` is the output of the first one. I see that `SequentialChain` passes only the outputs of the first (`c`) to the second chain. Is there any way to currently do it, without having to implement my own `SequentialChain` equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we have two sequential chains named `first_chain` and `second_chain`. First, we need to define these chains separately. Afterward, we can call `SequentialChain`, passing both chains along with `input_variables`.

Once we have defined `input_variables`, we can call them at any point in the chain by enclosing the variable name in curly braces, like this: `{a}`

The result of each chain will be saved in the variable name we specified when creating the chain in `output_key`

Finally, the last step of the chain will return both `input_variables` and `output_variables`

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SequentialChain

chat_model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)

# definition of the first prompt and chain
first_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    "How much is {a} + {b}. Answer only witht the result\nResult: "
)

first_chain = LLMChain(llm=chat_model,
                      prompt=first_prompt,
                      output_key="c")  # variable name for the chain's output

# definition of second prompt and chain
second_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    "How much is {a} times {c}"
)

second_chain = LLMChain(llm=chat_model,
                      prompt=second_prompt,
                      output_key="d")

# all together
full_chain= SequentialChain(
    chains=[first_chain, second_chain],
    input_variables=["a", "b"],
    output_variables=["c", "d"])

full_chain({"a":2,"b":3})
```

### With LangChain Expression Language (LCEL)

```
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough

model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)

# first chain
first_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    "How much is {a} + {b}. Answer only witht the result\nResult: "
)
first_chain = first_prompt | model | StrOutputParser()

# second_chain
second_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    "How much is {a} times {c}"
)
second_chain = second_prompt | model | StrOutputParser()

# all together
complete_chain = ({
        "c": first_chain, # save result in variable 'c'
        "a": itemgetter("a")  # get variable a for next chain
        }
    | second_chain # run second_chain with a and c as input
    )

complete_chain.invoke({'a': 2, 'b':3})
```

This will only return the result from `second_chain`  if you want also the intermediate results just change to:

```
complete_chain = ({
        "a": itemgetter("a"),
        "b": itemgetter("b"),
        "c": first_chain
        } 
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(d=second_chain)
    )

complete_chain.invoke({'a': 2, 'b':3})
```

Comment: It is not marked as resolved, but I can confirm that the LCEL solution works like a charm. I didn't test the LLMChain option due to the legacy warning in the docs: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains

Comment: Yes, LLMChain is being deprecated, LCEL is now the recommended option based on their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 'a' to the second chain as the input variables the same you do for your first chain.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).